# Is using nested try-except an acceptable Python style here

Tags: python, nested, try-catch

I need check whether the string `price` is an integer or a float and return `True` in this case or `False` otherwise.

Is this function written in an acceptable Python style?

```
def is_valid_price(price):
    try:
        int(price)
        return True
    except:
        try:
            float(price)
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

If no, what's the best way to make it look Pythony?

Comment: Is the `int` test necessary? Is there any string where `int` succeeds but `float` fails?

Comment: bare excepts are a bad practice, so this isn't merely bad *style*, it is bad code

Comment: Why nest it? Just check if you can convert to float, that covers both cases. You should never use a bare `except`, though, as you could end up hiding too many exceptions. A good practice is to only catch the exceptions you explicitly want to, so here, it would be `except ValueError:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not — `except` without specifying the exception class(es) is prone to make problems.

```
def is_valid_price(price):
    try:
        float(price)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

There is no need to use test `int(price)`, because if the string is convertible to `int`, it's also convertible to float.

Comment: Your code is irrelevant. The OP wants to test if a **string** represents a valid integer or float. Also, you should generally rather use `isinstance` to check types.

Comment: @Thierry, you're right, thanks! I replaced my code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you only check type of price:

```
def is_valid_price(price):
    return isinstance(price, (int, float))

is_valid_price(5)
```

You can call exception

```
assert float(price)
```

if price not float(int) you will get exception

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 assert float(price)

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: price

Comment: That's irrelevant. The OP wants to test if a **string** represents a valid integer or float.

Comment: This piece of code would return`False` for any string, even if it represents a valid price.

Comment: This is totally not the equivalent at all.